# Groupby in Pandas yields Groupby Object rather than Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `Pandas` `dataframe` that shows how much money people spent over the month of January and February. I would like to use a `groupby` function to group the months by person, but my code is yielding a `DataFrameGroupBy object` rather than an actual dataframe. I also have a column for gender that I would just like to leave in place.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Person A', 5, 21, 'Male'], ['Person B', 15, 3, 'Female']], columns=['Names', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Gender'])
print df.groupby(['Names', 'Jan', 'Feb'])
```

output:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x020D4470>
```

Starting dataframe:

```
      Names  Jan  Feb  Gender
0  Person A    5   21    Male
1  Person B   15    3    Female
```

Desired Output:

```
            Names  Value    Gender
0  Person A - Jan      5     Male
1  Person A - Feb     21     Male
2  Person B - Jan     15     Female
3  Person B - Feb      3     Female
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using stack.

```
df_out = df.set_index(['Names']).stack().to_frame().reset_index()
df_out.columns = ['Names','month','value']
```

**Edit**

This should also work:

```
stack_df = df.set_index(['Names', 'Gender']).stack().to_frame().reset_index()
stack_df.columns = ['Names','Gender','Month', 'Value']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), then concanecate columns and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `variable`:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Names').sort_values('Names')
df1['Names'] = df1['Names'] + '- ' + df1['variable']
df1 = df1.drop('variable', axis=1)
print df1
           Names  value
0  Person A- Jan      5
2  Person A- Feb     21
1  Person B- Jan     15
3  Person B- Feb      3
```

Another one line solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
print pd.melt(df, id_vars='Names').sort_values('Names')
        .assign(Names = lambda x: x['Names'] + '- ' + x['variable'])
        .drop('variable', axis=1)

           Names  value
0  Person A- Jan      5
2  Person A- Feb     21
1  Person B- Jan     15
3  Person B- Feb      3
```

EDIT:

You can add new column to parameter `id_vars`:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Names', 'Gender']).sort_values('Names')
df1['Names'] = df1['Names'] + '- ' + df1['variable']
df1 = df1.drop('variable', axis=1)
df1 = df1[['Names','value','Gender']]
print df1
           Names  value  Gender
0  Person A- Jan      5    Male
2  Person A- Feb     21    Male
1  Person B- Jan     15  Female
3  Person B- Feb      3  Female
```

One line solution, if you need reorder columns use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Names', 'Gender'])
        .sort_values('Names')
        .assign(Names = lambda x: x['Names'] + '- ' + x['variable'])
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .reindex_axis(['Names','value','Gender'], axis=1)

           Names  value  Gender
0  Person A- Jan      5    Male
2  Person A- Feb     21    Male
1  Person B- Jan     15  Female
3  Person B- Feb      3  Female
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't familiar with `melt`. With that solution my question was overly simplified, so I modified to the original as there was one column I wanted to leave in place.